# How should we handle loading CSS files correctly in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

**The error**

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css:8:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
|  */
> :root {
|   --bs-blue: #0d6efd;
|   --bs-indigo: #6610f2;
```

**The question**

I keep getting this error when I try to import `bootstrap.css`. Some solutions I have looked at involve adding a css loader in webpack.config.js but as I have installed my app using `angular-cli`, I'm unable to see it.

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ECS2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ecs2",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ECS2:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "ECS2:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ECS2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ecs2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

I'm importing bootstrap like this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';



import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';


import '../styles.css';

import { Inject, enableProdMode, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css', '../styles.css']
})



export class AppComponent {
  ...
}
```

**Attempted Solutions**

- Tried installing other version of bootstrap, same error
- Currently trying custom-webpack builder, but not sure if that will work.

Comment: You can’t import css like that. What do you need? Angular will include the styles you have added to the styles block in angular.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular application, you should not load CSS files like you mentioned in AppComponent File.

You have correctly added bootstrap files in angular.json and this will be suffice to include it in the angular project.

Please remove the import from Appcomponent file and try to build it. I have built several angular applications without any issues ( created via Angular CLI ).

Please let us know the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have migrated an app from Angular 4.2 to 14.* and I was getting errors for compiling CSS. It's been hours but couldn't find the solution your answer gave me the solution I had not even imagined if someone had `import`ed CSS in component instead of passing it from `styleUrls`
Thumbs Up to you :-)